# How atomic are mongoengine's operations

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to transition between object's state like so:

```
User.objects(id=user_id, state=STATE_WAITING).update_one(set__state=STATE_FINISHED)
```

The **question** is, can there be a situation where two processes will make the **same** operation asynchronously and succeed?

If so, can this operation be atomic, so the next process that will try to update the user (at the same time asynchronously), will fail because it's status will be already "finished"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing on a single document, the operation is atomic.

> [In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single
>   document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents
>   within a single document.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity-and-transactions)

When writing on multiple documents that is not atomic.

Further, a multi document transaction can be simulated using a two phase commit, details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#perform-two-phase-commits).